# Where does the R dθ triangle side length come from in this Coulomb's Law, infinite line charge example?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm reading Purcell & Morin's *E&M 3rd edition*.  In section 1.12, they demonstrate how Gauss's Law can save effort over Coulomb's by solving the same "infinite line charge" example using both methods, one arduous and one nearly trivial.

The physics is fine and if I take all of their expressions on faith, everything follows nicely.  But when trying to re-work the Coulomb's half of the example for myself, I wasn't able to figure out where one of the terms in their diagram comes from.

After dredging up as many other "infinite line charge" examples as I could, the approach seems to be a common one: exchanging the integral across the line of charge in terms of $dx$ (from $-\infty$ to $\infty$) for one that sweeps out the angle in terms of $d\theta$ (from $-2\pi$ to $2\pi$) via a change of variable.

This diagram accompanies the following text:
[image: Figure 1.24 from Purcell & Morin 3rd Ed.]

> It is convenient to use $\theta$ as the variable of integration.  Since Figs. 1.24(a) and (b) tell us that $R = r/cos \theta$ and $dx = R\,d\theta/cos \theta$, we have $dx = r\,d\theta/cos^2\theta$.  (This expression for $dx$ comes up often.  It also follows from $x = r\,tan\theta \Rightarrow dx = r\,d(tan\theta)=r\,d\theta/cos^2\theta$.)

If I already assume the $R\,d\theta$ that I've underlined in orange in the diagram, all of that (and the result that follows) makes perfect sense.  But I haven't been able to figure out where it came from.

Whenever I see a triangle, I get out the SohCahToa hammer.  In this case, I see a long, thin triangle with angle $d\theta$ at point $P$ with adjacent side $R$.  Wouldn't that make the opposite side $R\,tan\,d\theta$ instead of $R\,d\theta$?  It feels weird just seeing an angle multiplied by a length.  The text plays a little fast and loose with differentials-as-variables for my tastes, so I'm not even sure which role the $d\theta$ is supposed to be filling there.

Despite looking over this for an hour, I can feel it in my bones that I'm missing something simple!  I would appreciate any help uncovering my discrepancy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [arc length formula](https://themathpage.com/aTrig/arc-length.htm)  to get $s=Rd\theta$. Yes, indeed, arc length is angle in radians times radius by definition.

You are on the right track too. When  $d\theta <<1$, the other two angles are close to 90$^\circ$ , $\tan d\theta \approx\frac{s}{R}$, therefore $\tan \theta\approx d\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

The narrow differential triangle at right has angles $ (\pi/2,\pi/2- d \theta, d \theta ) $ ... so we can draw the narrow triangle like:

[image]

where $ Rd \theta $ is the side or (differential) arc length.